# How can i write date format in thinkphp

Tags: php, date, thinkphp

How can i write Date format in Thinkphp?

I given the below line in my coding

```
{$user.sdate}
```

It shows like 10-07-1991

but i want like 10:22pm, 10-jul-1991

Every format i tried but it does not work.

I tried this below one but no use

```
{$user.sdate|date="H:i dd-M-YYYY",###}


{$user.sdate|date="dd-M-YYYY",###}


{$user.sdate|date="H:i d-m-Y",###}
```

Please help me. Because i tried this from long days. I know this is just single step but i searched google. I am not getting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = date( 'H:i a , d-F-Y ', strtotime($user[0]['date']) ) ;
```

Output:

```
05:55 pm , 10-June-2017
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

`{$user.sdate|date="h:i a d-M-Y",###}`

Comment: pay attention that the `$user.sdate` should be a timestamp

Comment: This is in Timestamp only but now it shows like 2017-07-10 13:13:24.732038

Comment: there is my controller:  `namespace Home\Controller;
use Think\Controller;
class IndexController extends Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->assign('date',time());
  $this->display();
    }
}`,  there is the view's code `{$date|date="h:i a d-M-Y",###}`, and the result is **04:43 pm 10-Jul-2017**

Comment: still not getting

Comment: No working fine in corephp and codeigniter. But not worked in Thinkphp